# How can I easily write simple tactics at the ML level of Isabelle?

Tags: sml, isabelle

In an Isabelle theory file, I can write simple one-line tactics such as the following:

```
apply (clarsimp simp: split_def split: prod.splits)
```

I find, however, when I start writing ML code to automate proofs, to produce an ML `tactic` object, these one-liners become rather verbose:

```
clarsimp_tac (Context.proof_map (
    Simplifier.map_ss (fold Splitter.add_split @{thms prod.splits})
    #> Simplifier.map_ss (fn ss => ss addsimps [@{thm split_def}]))
  @{context}) 1
```

Is there an easier way to write the simple one-line tactics at the Isabelle/ML level?

For example, something like an anti-quotation: `@{tactic "clarsimp simp: split_def split: prod.splits"}` producing a function of type `context -> tactic`, would be an ideal solution.

Comment: You might want to look into the code of `try0`. AFAIK, it does a similar trick to what you propose with your anti-quotation.

Comment: @LarsNoschinski: `try0` initially looked promising, but unfortunately works using proof-state (`state`) objects, which still can't be used in a situation where a `tactic` is called for. A possible approach could be to inject a partially-proven `thm` into a new proof state object, apply a method to it, and then extract the result; unfortunately it seems that there is no obvious mechanism to do this either.

Comment: With several questions and answers and comments spread over them, it is getting a bit difficult to follow.  Better start a plain-old mailing list discussion at `isabelle-users`.

Answer (score 6):

I see a variety of possibilities, it depends a bit on the context of your the application what is best.  Note that in general, individual ML code for proof automated used to be common-place in the very old times, but it is relatively rare today.  For example, compare the amount of custom tactics in rather small [HOL-Bali](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/library/HOL/HOL-Bali/index.html) (started in 1997) with the large [JinjaThreads](http://afp.sourceforge.net/entries/JinjaThreads.shtml) in AFP (started in 2007 and continued until recently).

Nesting ML antiquotations like `@{tactic}` would in principle work, but you would quickly run into further questions, like what happens if your theorem arguments should be again Isar or ML source.

Instead of *antiquoting* tactic building blocks in ML, a more basic approach is to *quote* your proof precedure in Isar by giving it regular method syntax like this:

```
ML {*
  (*foo_tac -- the payload of what you want to do,
    note the dependency on ctxt: Proof.context*)
  fun foo_tac ctxt =
    let
      val my_ctxt =
        ctxt |> Simplifier.map_simpset
         (fold Splitter.add_split @{thms prod.splits} #>
          Simplifier.add_simp @{thm split_def})
    in ALLGOALS (clarsimp_tac my_ctxt) end
*}

method_setup foo = {*
  (*concrete syntax like "clarsimp", "auto" etc.*)
  Method.sections Clasimp.clasimp_modifiers >>
    (*Isar method boilerplate*)
    (fn _ => fn ctxt => SIMPLE_METHOD (CHANGED (foo_tac ctxt)))  
*}
```

Here I've first made a conventional `foo_tac` definition in Isabelle/ML, and then wrapped it up the usual Isar way as proof method.  The latter means you have wrappers like `SIMPLE_METHOD` taking care of pushing "chained facts" into your goal state, and `CHANGED` to ensure that the Isar method makes progress (like `simp` or `auto`).

The `foo_tac` example assumes that your modification of the context (or its simpset) is constant, by the hard-wired split rules.  If you want to have further parameters there, you can include that in the concrete method syntax.  Note that `Method.sections` is already quite sophisticated in this respect.  More basic argument parsers are given in the section "Defining proof methods" of the [isar-ref](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/doc/isar-ref.pdf) manual.  You should also look at existing examples by searching the sources for `method_setup` (in Isabelle/Isar) or `Method.setup` (in Isabelle/ML).

If you still want to do ML antiquotations instead of concrete method syntax, one could try a variant of `@{context}` that allows modifiers like this:

```
@{context simp add: ...}
```

That is a bit speculative, invented on the spot, and might turn out as bad practice.  As I've said, fine-grained tactic programming in Isabelle became a bit out of use in recent years, although ML is an integral part of the Isabelle framework.  If you pose a more concrete question with more of the application context, we can reconsider the antiquotation approach.

Comment: I am not wedded to using an anti-quotation (how to add arguments from ML variables is a good point), but rather am just looking for a convenient way to instantiate off-the-shelf Isabelle tactics (such as `clarsimp`, `auto`, etc) from within ML code. The context is the [AutoCorres](http://ssrg.nicta.com.au/projects/TS/autocorres/) project, which needs to generate many proofs based on user C code automatically. Writing/prototyping such automated proof methods can become quite tedious using the Isabelle ML interface that I have used in my question.

Comment: The example of `foo_tac` and method `foo` above were meant as such a "convenient instantiation" of clarsimp, auto.  Instead of inlining large `tactic` ML expressions, you have a mix of auxiliary ML tactics and Isar method syntax.  You can also look at src/HOL/Auth in the Isabelle sources as an example with many specific ML tactics and Isar methods in that sense (it is an updated version of a classic tactic-only application of Isabelle from the 1990-ies).

Comment: `src/HOL/Auth` appears to be crafting methods to help solve theorems inside hand-written theory files. In my context, I am solving theorems that have been dynamically created based on an input C file---there is no proof script at the bottom, but rather I am dealing with `thm` objects generated by `Goal.init`, which require a `tactic` to process. When developing such tactics, I often just want to use "built-in" Isabelle tactics, but without the verbosity of generating the equivalent of a `foo_tac` body for every such use.

Answer (score 3):

Additional to the other answers, I think it's worth mentioning that there is a new high-level tactic/proof method construction language (similar to Ltac in Coq) called [Eisbach](http://ssrg.nicta.com.au/projects/TS/tactics.pml) in Isabelle2015, which aims to be easier to understand and maintain.

Answer (score 1):

The `Method` class appear to provide enough of an interface to extract out a tactic, via a `cases_tactic` as follows:

```
(*
 * Generate an ML tactic object of the given Isar string.
 *
 * For example,
 *
 *   mk_tac "auto simp: field_simps intro!: ext" @{context}
 *
 * will generate the corresponding "tactic" object.
 *)
fun mk_tac str ctxt =
let
  val parsed_str = Outer_Syntax.scan Position.start str
      |> filter Token.is_proper
      |> Args.name
  val meth = Method.method (Proof_Context.theory_of ctxt)
      (Args.src (parsed_str, Position.start)) ctxt
in
  Method.apply (K meth) ctxt [] #> Seq.map snd
end
```

or alternatively as an anti-quotation:

```
(*
 * Setup an antiquotation of the form:
 *
 *    @{tactic "auto simp: foo intro!: bar"}
 *
 * which returns an object of type "context -> tactic".
 *
 * While this doesn't provide any benefits over a direct call to "mk_tac" just
 * yet, in the future it may generate code to avoid parsing the tactic at
 * run-time.
 *)
val tactic_antiquotation_setup =
let
  val parse_string =
    ((Args.context -- Scan.lift Args.name) >> snd)
      #>> ML_Syntax.print_string
      #>> (fn s => "mk_tac " ^ s)
      #>> ML_Syntax.atomic
in
  ML_Antiquote.inline @{binding "tactic"} parse_string
end
```

and setup in a theory file as follows:

```
setup {*
  tactic_antiquotation_setup
*}
```

which can then be used as follows:

```
lemma "(a :: nat) * (b + 1) = (a * b) + a"
  by (tactic {* @{tactic "metis Suc_eq_plus1 mult_Suc_right nat_add_commute"} @{context} *})
```

as desired.